# Remove Some Numbers in an Ordered List

Tags: html, css

I would like to skip numbering on the first few items of an ordered list.

```
   First
   Second
   Third
1. Fourth
2. Fifth
3. Sixth
```

Limitations: the `<ol>` is in column-count: 2 and I don't want to wrap two lists in a DIV to get them to behave.

No code that I have tried has come close to achieving this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the start value and consider `nth-child()` to hide the first 3

```css
li:nth-child(-n + 3) {
  list-style: none;
}

ol {
  column-count: 2
}
```

```html
<ol start="-2">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
  <li>Sixth</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just remove the `<li>` from the first few elements

```
<ol>
  Coffee
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thats invalid html